# MSQL show how many mutual friends while selecting all users

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I show count of `mutual friend` along with users details?
I have two table `USERS_TABLE` and `TABLE_USERS_FRIENDS`, I will like to show all users in `USERS_TABLE` then based on my current session id I want to show count of mutual friends I have with every user. I have attempted below code but it didn't work.

Users Table

```
    user_uuid   | user_name | user_gender 
----------------|-----------|---------------
001-e74-9a5-83  | Peter     | Male
002-eed-b4e-6b  | Devindra  | Male
003-b61-4df-be  | Peggy     | Female
004-f9b-9da-d1  | Lucy      | Female
005-gx1-6hz-5o  | Priya     | Female
```

Users Friends Table

```
    owner_uuid  | friend_uuid 
----------------|-----------------
001-e74-9a5-83  | 003-b61-4df-be
002-eed-b4e-6b  | 003-b61-4df-be
```

Query

```
SET @session = "001-e74-9a5-83";

SELECT u.user_uuid, u.user_name, u.user_gender, COUNT(a.mutual_friend_uuid) AS mutual_friends

FROM TABLE_USERS u

JOIN(
    SELECT CASE 
    WHEN friend_uuid = u.user_uuid
        THEN owner_uuid 
    ELSE friend_uuid 
        END AS mutual_friend_uuid 
    FROM TABLE_USERS_FRIENDS 
        WHERE friend_uuid = u.user_uuid 
    OR owner_uuid = u.user_uuid
) a
JOIN( 
    SELECT CASE 
    WHEN friend_uuid = @session
        THEN owner_uuid 
    ELSE friend_uuid 
        END AS mutual_friend_uuid 
    FROM TABLE_USERS_FRIENDS 
        WHERE friend_uuid = @session 
    OR owner_uuid = @session
) b
ON b.mutual_friend_uuid = a.mutual_friend_uuid
```

Expected result

```
    user_uuid   | user_name | user_gender | mutual_friends
----------------|-----------|-------------|-----------------
002-eed-b4e-6b  | Devindra  | Male        | 1
003-b61-4df-be  | Peggy     | Female      | 0
004-f9b-9da-d1  | Lucy      | Female      | 0
005-gx1-6hz-5o  | Priya     | Female      | 0
```

[SQL FIDDLE LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/yO_eeCNO)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [user_uuid], [user_name] ,[user_gender],ISNULL([mutual_friends],0) AS [mutual_friends] 
FROM TABLE_USERS (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT owner_uuid ,COUNT(friend_uuid) AS 
            [mutual_friends] FROM TABLE_USERS_FRIENDS (NOLOCK) 
            GROUP BY owner_uuid) AS Temp
ON Temp.owner_uuid = TABLE_USERS.user_uuid
```